# ParseException when launch a test in phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have just installed new phpunit 5.4 from an older version and now when I launch a test I have:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException: Found unknown escape character "\S" at line 14 (near ""Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User":"). in phar:///home/nextop/.phpbrew/bin/phpunit/symfony/yaml/Unescaper.php:117
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well PHPUnit 5.4 uses `"symfony/yaml": "~2.1|~3.0"` and [since version 3.0](https://github.com/symfony/yaml/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of symfony/yaml:

> Yaml::parse() now throws an exception when a blackslash is not escaped
>   in double-quoted strings

So I would search your codebase for string cases of "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" which seem to be causing the problem. I hope (for you) that it's just an unescaped backslash in one of your tests and not in the Sonata bundle itself..